# Security review: Some files and directories in your install are writable by the server

Tags: 8, security

I am running Drupal 8 on a vps running latest ispconfig/apache fastCGI.

Security review module reports: "Some files and directories in your install are writable by the server." and basically lists all my files.

Now all files are set with the correct permissions: 644 for files, 755 for directories.

I suspect the problem is file ownership. 
Ispconfig creates a new user for each site and they belong to a client group.

So for this site all files belong to: web65:client0

which means: owner is web65 and group is client0

And I noticed the www-data user is a part of the client0 group.

Is this the problem? That the webserver is a member of the client group?
And what would be the best fix?
I suspect this is a problem for all ispconfig users?

Any ideas?

Comment: What user is the web server running as? It shouldn't matter that www-data is part of the group, no, as the group doesn't have write perms

Comment: the webserver is running as www-data